# Solving Concurrency using arrays in C++ and POSIX

Tags: c++, concurrency, operating-system, posix

I'm looking for any guidance on how to solve concurrency problem that will emerge when two processes are trying to access a shared resource (text file). The solution must use an algorithm and an array as a data structure to coordinate and arrange the execution of these two processes to solve concurrency.

I'm using C++ and POSIX API and I have read about several solutions to solve concurrency, but they use semaphores, locks and other methods but not arrays. Any guidance on how to do it using arrays?

Comment: Unless you explain your problem in detail it is not possible to provide any meaningful advice. What are you trying to do? Explain that in detail.

Comment: What do you mean "using arrays", is the resource you are sharing an array?  Is there something you are trying to accomplish that a mutex or semaphore won't do?

Comment: Thanks for your replies guys. This is a homework given to us in the OS course and the doctor wants us to solve concurrency issue that will emerge if two processes are going to access a shared resource (text file). Now to solve it, he wants us to use an array data structure that will coordinate the access to the shared resource and which will arrange the sequence of these two processes execution .. 

I have been searching in the net but couldn't find anything else except Mutex, semaphores and locks .. so are you familiar with the array method to solve concurrency guys ? Thanks for your time

Comment: Try giving us an example of an instance of the concurrency problem you need to solve. What steps does each process perform, in what order with respect to each other, and what goes wrong? Right now it seems like we are missing part of the question.

Comment: @ moonshadow : thanks for your reply. As I said, I still don't have a full understanding of what I should do. Its a homework assigned to us. you can consider that each process will try to write to the file at the same time. Now how can we maintain their execution order using an algorith and an array data structure ? the idea is not about the exact code or lines its just about the method of arranging the process execution using arrays which is confusing to me also because I know there are lucks, semaphores but never heared of simulating it using an array data structure actually ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are being asked to produce an implementation of [Peterson's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm) (or similar). This uses an integer and an array of booleans to implement a mutex, without requiring any platform support for synchronisation/atomic operations.

Comment: Thanks alot for your time man. I have been looking into these algorithms and they all look similar : 


http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion#Software_solutions

Do you think Peterson's is the closest one to the situation I explained in my question ?